# How to link multiple Docker containers and encapsulate the result?

Tags: docker, encapsulation, docker-network

I have a Node.js web-application that connects to a Neo4j database. I would like to encapsulate these in a single Docker image (using also a [Neo4j Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j/)), but I'm a docker novice and can't seem to figure this out. What's the recommended way to do it in the latest Docker versions?

My intuition would be to run the Neo4j container *nested inside* the app container. But from what I've read, I think the supported / recommended approach is to link the containers together. What I need is pretty well illustrated in [this image](http://codentrick.com/home/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Docker_Linking_Dual.jpg). But [the article](http://codentrick.com/advanced-usecase-with-docker-connecting-containers/) where the image comes from isn't clear to me. Anyway, it's using the soon-to-be-deprecated [legacy container linking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/), while [networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networkingcontainers/) is recommended these days. A tutorial or explanation would be much appreciated.

Also, how does [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) fit into all this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Running a container within another container would imply to run a *Docker engine* within a Docker container. This is referenced as *dind* for Docker-in-Docker and I would strongly advise against it. You can search 'dind' online and discover why in most cases it is a bad idea, but as it is not the main object of your question I won't extend this subject any further.

#### Running both a node.js process and a neo4j process in the same container

While most people will tell you to refrain yourself from running more than one process within a Docker container, nothing prevents you from doing so. If you want to follow this path, take a look at the [Using Supervisor with Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/using_supervisord/) from the Docker documentation website, or at the [Phusion baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) Docker image.

Just be aware that this way of doing things will make your Docker image more and more difficult to maintain over time.

#### Linking containers

As you found out, keeping Docker images as simple as you can (i.e: running one and only one app within a Docker container) will make your life easier on the long term.

Linking containers together is trivial when both containers run on the same Docker engine. It is just a matter of:

- having your neo4j container [expose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) the port its service listens on
- running your node.js container with the `--link <neo4j container name>:<alias>` option
- within the node.js application configuration, set the neo4j host to the `<alias>` hostname, docker will take care of forwarding that connection to the IP it assigned to the neo4j container

When you want to run those two containers on different hosts, things get more difficult.

With Docker Compose, you have to use the [`link:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) key to define your links

#### The new Docker network feature

You also discovered that linking containers won't be supported in the future and that the new way of making multiple Docker containers communicate is to create a virtual network and attach those 2 containers to that network.

Here's how to proceed:

```
docker network create mynet
docker run --detach --name myneo4j --net mynet neo4j
docker run --detach --name mynodejs --net mynet <your nodejs image>
```

Your node application configuration should then use `myneo4j` as the host to connect to.

<strike>To tell Docker Compose to use the new network feature, you would have to use the [`--x-networking`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) option. Also you would not use the `links:` key.</strike>

Using the new networking feature also means that you won't be able to define any *alias* for the db. As a result you have to use the *container name*. Beware that unless you use the [`container_name:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container-name) key in your *docker-compose.yml* file, Compose will create container names based on the directory which contains your *docker-compose.yml* file, the service name as found in the yml file and a number.

For instance, the following *docker-compose.yml* file, if within a directory named "foo" would create two containers named `foo_web_1` and `foo_db_1`:

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
db:
  image: postgres
```

when started with `docker-compose --x-networking up`, the web app configuration should then use `foo_db_1` as the db hostname.

While if you use `container_name`:

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
db:
  image: postgres
  container_name: mydb
```

when started with `docker-compose --x-networking up`, the web app configuration should then use `mydb` as the db hostname.

---

### Example of using Docker Compose to run a web app using nodeJS and neo4j

In this example, I will show how to dockerize the example app from [github project aseemk/node-neo4j-template](https://github.com/aseemk/node-neo4j-template) which uses nodejs and neo4j.

I assume you already have [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) 1.9.0+ and [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) 1.5+ installed.

This project will use 2 docker containers, one to run the neo4j database and one to run the nodeJS web app.

#### Dockerizing the web app

We need to build a *Docker image* from which Docker compose will run a container. For that, we will write a *Dockerfile*.

Create a file named `Dockerfile` (mind the capital `D`) with the following content:

```
FROM node
RUN git clone https://github.com/aseemk/node-neo4j-template.git
WORKDIR /node-neo4j-template
RUN npm install
# ugly 20s sleep to wait for neo4j to initialize
CMD sleep 20s && node app.js
```

This *Dockerfile* describes the steps the Docker engine will have to follow to *build* a *docker image* for our web app. This docker image will:

- be based on the [official node docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/node/)
- clone the nodeJS example project from [Github](https://github.com/aseemk/node-neo4j-template)
- change the working directory to the directory containing the git clone
- run the `npm install` command to download and install the nodeJS app dependencies
- instruct docker which command to use when running a container of that image

A quick review of the nodeJS code reveals that the author allows us to configure the URL to use to [connect to the neo4j database](https://github.com/aseemk/node-neo4j-template/blob/master/models/user.js#L10) using the `NEO4J_URL` environment variable.

#### Dockerizing the neo4j database

Well people took care of that for us already. We will use the [official Docker image for neo4j](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/neo4j/) which can be found on the Docker Hub.

A quick review of the readme tells us to use the `NEO4J_AUTH` environment variable to change the neo4j password. And setting this variable to `none` will disable the authentication all together.

#### Setting up Docker Compose

In the same directory as the one containing our *Dockerfile*, create a *docker-compose.yml* file with the following content:

```
db:
  container_name: my-neo4j-db
  image: neo4j
  environment:
    NEO4J_AUTH: none

web:
  build: .
  environment:
    NEO4J_URL: http://my-neo4j-db:7474
  ports:
    - 80:3000
```

This Compose configuration file describes 2 services: `db` and `web`.

The `db` service will produce a container named `my-neo4j-db` from the official *neo4j* docker image and will start that container setting up the `NEO4J_AUTH` environment variable to `none`.

The `web` service will produce a container named at docker compose discretion using a docker image *built from the Dockerfile found in the current directory* (`build: .`). It will start that container setting up the environment variable `NEO4J_URL` to `http://my-neo4j-db:7474` (note how we use here the name of the neo4j container `my-neo4j-db`). Furthermore, docker compose will instruct the Docker engine to expose the `web` container's port `3000` on the docker host port `80`.

#### Firing it up

Make sure you are in the directory that contains the *docker-compose.yml* file and type: `docker-compose --x-networking up`.

Docker compose will read the *docker-compose.yml* file, figure out it has to first build a docker image for the `web` service, then create and start both containers and finally will provide you with the logs from both containers.

Once the log shows `web_1       | Express server listening at: http://localhost:3000/`, everything is cooked and you can direct your Internet navigator to `http://<ip of the docker host>/`.

To stop the application, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

If you want to start the app in the background, use `docker-compose --x-networking up -d` instead. Then in order to display the logs, run `docker-compose logs`.

To stop the service: `docker-compose stop`

To delete the containers: `docker-compose rm`

#### Making neo4j storage persistent

The official neo4j docker image readme says the container persists its data on a volume at `/data`. We then need to instruct Docker Compose to mount that volume to a directory on the docker host.

Change the *docker-compose.yml* file with the following content:

```
db:
  container_name: my-neo4j-db
  image: neo4j
  environment:
    NEO4J_AUTH: none
  volumes:
    - ./neo4j-data:/data

web:
  build: .
  environment:
    NEO4J_URL: http://my-neo4j-db:7474
  ports:
    - 80:3000
```

With that config file, when you will run `docker-compose --x-networking up`, docker compose will create a `neo4j-data` directory and mount it into the container at location `/data`.

#### Starting a 2nd instance of the application

Create a new directory and copy over the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files.

We then need to edit the *docker-compose.yml* file to avoid name conflict for the neo4j container and the port conflict on the docker host.

Change its content to:

```
db:
  container_name: my-neo4j-db2
  image: neo4j
  environment:
    NEO4J_AUTH: none
  volumes:
    - ./neo4j-data:/data

web:
  build: .
  environment:
    NEO4J_URL: http://my-neo4j-db2:7474
  ports:
    - 81:3000
```

Now it is ready for the `docker-compose --x-networking up` command. Note that you must be in the directory with that new *docker-compose.yml* file to start the 2nd instance up.

Comment: Thanks! This is already quite helpful. But if possible, I'd like a few things clarified: **[1]** It would be great if you could slightly augment the last part with the assumption that the reader doesn't know anything about `docker-compose` (which happens to be the case for me). **[2]** Can your final configuration there be used to start multiple instances of the same setup? (The arguments that define a particular instance would be the exposed web-http-port, the exposed neo4j-port and the exposed neo4j-directory to make storage persistent.)

Comment: @mhelvens That's a lot of work, but since I found a nodeJS project using neo4j I was able to get it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! :-) Ideally, I'd like to use a one-line command to spin a new server, but if Docker cannot do this for me, I can just write a bash-script.

Comment: Oh, and it seems that a volume for Neo4j need (can?) no longer be mapped to any local directory for persistence. The docker daemon seems to have centralized storage for [data-volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/).

Comment: That's a different way to handle the persistence. Both work and the one I shown is not announced to be ever deprecated

Comment: Hm. I tried your way on the command line before (without docker-compose), and it would complain about invalid characters (referring to "/").